# Assigning parameter value in function declaration?

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor

I don't understand why in this constructor declaration, the input parameter is assigned 2.

What does it mean? Does it mean that by default (unless something else is passed), size will be 2?

```
Graph(int size = 2);
```

I've never seen syntax like this, so I don't even know how to Google it :/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, the parameter value will be 2 by default.

So you can call it normally:

```
Graph g(5);
```

in which case `size` will be equal to 5,

or you can call it without providing a value:

```
Graph g;
```

in which case `size` will be equal to 2.

Note: `Graph g();` is actually a function declaration, not a construction/initialization. C and C++ allow you to **declare** functions inside other functions. `Graph g();` is the declaration of a function `g` that takes no arguments and returns a `Graph` object by value.

Comment: So, does that mean I can create a new Graph without adding an int parameter at all?

Comment: @OleksiyDobrodum By the way, you can do this with functions as well.

Comment: Do you mean any functions, not necessarily members? That's effectively overloading a function without re-writing it! Cool! Learning something new every day :)

Comment: @OleksiyDobrodum Yup, any functions. :) There are some restrictions, for example if your function takes 2 ints (e.g. int add(int x, int y), you cannot choose to have a default value for only the first one since it becomes ambiguous. I'm sure you can look up examples on it, just Google for 'C++ default parameters'.

Comment: `Graph g();` -- That's a function declaration. It's not calling the constructor.  Drop the parens.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Crap, you're right -- I saw this exact thing on another question 1h ago and forgot about it. Will edit